# Django - Zip multiple querysets with uncommon fields data

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have this one model where I have fetch `published count` , `under process count`, `rejected count`, `received count` on monthly basis

```
class PreData(models.Model):

    status=models.CharField(max_length=200,default=None,null=True)

    receivedon=models.DateField(default=None,blank=False,null=True)

    publishedon = models.DateField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

`received count` is based on monthly count of `receivedon` `DateField` in model, `published count` is based on monthly count of `publishedon` `DateField` in model, `rejected count` and `under process count` is based on count of specific `status` value of `CharField` in model.

I'm struggling after writing below queries,I'm clueless as to how fetch data to fill the columns(see figure). I'm not sure queries I wrote will help.

The problem comes when I want to zip `received_monthly_data` and  `published_monthly_data` but  `received_monthly_data` has data from April month and `published_monthly_data` didn't have April month. when i zip , results will loose April month. I am not able to figure how to do this.

```
received_monthly_data = PreData.objects.filter(journaluser=request.user.username).\
                annotate(month=TruncMonth('receivedon'),year=TruncYear('receivedon')).values('month','year').\
                annotate(c=Count('id')).order_by('-month')

published_monthly_data = PreData.objects.filter(Q(journaluser=request.user.username)&~Q(pdfsenton=None)). \
                annotate(month=TruncMonth('publishedon'), year=TruncYear('publishedon')).values('month', 'year'). \
                annotate(c=Count('id')).order_by('-month')


underproc_data= PreData.objects.filter(Q(journaluser=request.user.username)&~Q(status="[Published]"))
```

[I need the data to fill these columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJFfd.png)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use `itertools.zip_longest` which will zip the longest sequence and will substitute `None` for the missing values in the shorter sequence. That way you won't lose the April data.

If you wish to use a value other than `None`, specify the `fillvalue` argument.

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest

> itertools.zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=None)
>
> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables. If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are
>   filled-in with fillvalue. Iteration continues until the longest
>   iterable is exhausted.

Note that the function is called `itertools.izip_longest` in Python 2.

Comment: That Worked! Thank you very much @Will Keeling.

Comment: How do I access `fillvalue` arguments value in django templates?

Comment: It would be better to perform the zip in the view before handing the resulting list of data to the template. That way you wouldn't have to deal with the `fillvalue` in the template itself.

Comment: Yea I have done it the same way, however I couldn't get solution to my problem as zipping and iterating in template is making lot of for loop iterations in template and there's also other problem. So I kinda wanted to know if I can write my own dictionary to populate with only fields I wanted by iterating for loop for like 100 times in view it self? Will this be good?

Comment: Yes that sounds like a reasonable approach. It is always a good idea to keep the logic in the template simple by preprocessing the data in the view.

Comment: Oh great then, Thank you very much for suggestion! :)